# python: urllib2 using different network interface

Tags: python, sockets, networking, interface, network-interface

I have the following code:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

It's running on a machine with two network interfaces. I'd like to specify which interface I want the code to use. Specifically, I want it to use the one other than the one it is using by default... but I can figure out which is which if I can just pick the interface.

What's the easiest/best/most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I assume you can't change the system route values to force connection to your remote server use the other interface ?

Comment: @CédricJulien: That would work (if I could make all connections to a particular web-site go through the other interface), though I'm also interested to know how to do it in-code if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Not yet a complete solution, but if you were using only simple socket objects, you could do what you need this way :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))    # replace "127.0.0.1" by the local IP of the interface to use
s.connect(("remote_server.com", 80))
```

Thus, you will force the system to bind the socket to the wanted network interface.

Comment: If you're using linux, this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094-get-the-ip-address-associated-with-a-network-inter/) will be useful to map from interface name to IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Twisted's [`twisted.web.client.Agent`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html), then you can achieve this via:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent

agent = Agent(reactor, bindAddress=("10.0.0.1", 0))
```

And then using `agent` in the usual way.