# Bind to specific network interface in Python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

Would it be possible to launch several different python programs at once (via *Popen*) and have each one of them bind to a different interface?

Also once this is done does that mean all traffic coming from that python process will use that interface, since I plan to mix and match the `urllib2`, `mechanize`, and `Ghost.py` modules in the child processes.

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Do you want to listen on all traffic coming to the device? Do you want to assign different IP addresses to each of your processes?

Comment: The latter, Im trying to get each proccess to use a different IP address.

Comment: This not really a Python problem, but more of how Linux handles interface binding. It has been asked and [answered](http://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes) at superuser.com.

Comment: But wouldn't messing with an OS's routing tables or something along those lines change the IP address everything on the entire computer uses? I've see some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245810/python-urllib2-using-different-network-interface) on bind to an network interface using Python's socket library, but I don't know if this can be done in a multiprocessing way.

Comment: routing tables don't change IP addresses, they only work for managing how traffic flows across a connection.